# What are the advantages of self-testing code vs separated tests?

Tags: unit-testing, refactoring, tdd

Personally, I've always put unit tests in a separate project just because that's how MSTest seems to be set up.  But I'm reading *Refactoring: Improving the Design of Existing Code* by Martin Fowler and he seems to be advocating not only putting them in the same project, but also putting them in the same class as the method they're testing.

I'm really honestly having trouble thinking of ways this is different from having the tests in a separate area from the code itself other than philosophical differences (are tests documentation or clutter?).

Are there any clearcut reasons to choose one over another?  Or is this mainly a philosophical difference?

**UPDATE**:  I'm not necessarily convinced yet one way or another, but at least I have an idea what the arguments are.  I wish I could select everybody's answer, but I had to select just one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Perhaps there is some elegance to having self-testing code, but I tend to side with the same philosophy as you -- that code separation trumps some notion of abstract beauty.  When you design a class, you can fundamentally break it into three parts:

- What the class does (eg, the class' definition)
- How it does it (the implementation)
- How you use it (documentation and/or test cases)

I see test cases as serving the purpose of documentation, as well as part of a safety net in a test suite.  When a new programmer is looking at your code, possibly long after you've stopped working on it, the documentation is seldom the most effective way of communicating how the class should be used.  It can answer questions about how the code behaves in specific situations, providing a general overview of the class and it's methods, and so on, but the test cases provide a concrete example of how the class would be used in *real code*.

So for that reason, I would tend to say that they should remain outside of the class itself, since this re-enforces this degree of separation.

Answer (score 4):

Putting them in the same class being tested may break popular unit testing frameworks, as NUnit won't test types that don't have a default parameterless constructor.

Putting the tests in a different file but same project is better, but still causes your main project to reference testing frameworks like NUnit.Framework.dll as well as any mocking frameworks like Rhino.Mocks.dll.

Having your tests inside the class under test also increases the size of your distributed project.

Separate the tests out into a separate project, and you don't have any of these issues.

Answer (score 3):

Keeping your tests in a separate area (subdirectory, project, whatever) is a good way to retain the option to deploy *just* the production code, which is usually what you'll want to do.

Answer (score 2):

There's a lot of convenience in having your tests in the same class that you are testing. Quite often (and prior to embarking on TDD), I used add a Main method to the class just to test the functionality of the code I wrote. And I didn't remove the main method because it was quite useful to have the test code lying around. This was convenient, in the same sense that it is convenient to have documentation tied to your code. I didn't have to look else where or search for the test code.

Having said that, the point of TDD is not just about testing/quality-assurance. It's more about getting you to think about your design/interfaces. And from that view point, it makes sense to have your "test" (a.k.a "design") code in a separate file. Your "test" code is the client/user of your class.

If the purpose of writing tests in a separate file were a technical one, i.e "because the unit test framework was designed that way" or "otherwise you'll need to include a reference in your main project", or "it improves performance", that doesn't sound very convincing. If that were the case things would have been done very differently.

Answer (score 2):

I don't see any benefits in having test code and production code in the same class. Instead I see some disadvantages:

- It won't be possible to deploy and distribute the production code without the test code. So instead of a 100KB file you might need to ship a 200KB or larger file. (When using TDD, there lines of test code is often equal or greater to the lines of production code.)
- The structure of the tests is too tightly coupled with the production code. There should be no 1:1 relation between the tests and the production classes. Instead, there should be a 1:1 relation between tests and behaviour.

Quoted from http://blog.daveastels.com.s3.amazonaws.com/files/BDD_Intro.pdf

> "When you realize that it's all about specifying behaviour and not writing tests, your point of view shifts. Suddenly the idea of having a Test class for each of your production classes is ridiculously limiting. And the thought of testing each of your methods with its own test method (in a 1-1 relationship) will be laughable."

I program mainly in Java and I use Maven to build my projects. There I have the tests in the same module and package as the production classes that they operate on, but in a different directory (/src/main/java and /src/test/java). When Maven builds the project, it executes all tests, but only the production code is included in the binary distributable.

---

**Addendum: 10 years later (2019)**

Nowadays I'm mostly working in Clojure and I find it sometimes handy to write tests for a function right next it in the same file. This only applies to pure unit tests for little helper methods. (With static typing some of those tests might be unnecessary.) Clojure makes it possible to exclude the tests from the compiled production build, so that avoids the binary bloat. And since `clojure.test` is part of the standard library, writing simple tests in production files doesn't require additional dependencies.

Business logic tests, which are the majority of all tests, I still prefer keeping in a separate file. That way it's easier to focus on reading either the production code or the test code - how the system is implemented vs. what it's supposed to do - without needing to skip large pieces of interleaved code. And integration tests are *always* in a separate file due to the test setup clutter for setting up the database and other dependencies.

There's also the mirror side: Especially when starting on new stuff, I first implement the feature inside the test file. Then when the structure starts stabilizing, I extract parts of it to become production code. This approach is known as [TDD as if you Meant It](https://cumulative-hypotheses.org/2011/08/30/tdd-as-if-you-meant-it/). In a code kata I'll probably never extract the production code before deleting the project, but in a work project it'll eventually be split to production and test code.

Comment: It is only natural to write tests as 1-1 with the code it is testing. To try to test differently in the name of "testing behavior" simply means you have allowed an unnecessary difference between the code and the behavior. The code should be specifying the behavior. I mean this in terms of idealism, as it is almost impossible to achieve in reality, although I am getting closer and closer to this.

Comment: It has been 10 years since I wrote this answer, so I added an addendum about my current world view.

Answer (score 1):

It's mainly a philosophical difference I think.

There may be marginal performance advantages in having them in a separate project (in so much as your tests aren't deployed into production), but they probably are not *that* significant.

Also remember that *Refactoring* was written quite a while ago (in IT terms) so preferred practices may well have moved on since then.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some possible practical benefits of placing the test code directly in the class it is testing.

All of the following points are basically different effects that stem from how keeping the tests with the code makes it harder to ignore the tests. This reminds us that the code and the tests are highly related and equally important. Combining them helps us to merge the two concepts into one, achieving types (classes) that achieve better conceptual "compression" (think how classes are sometimes called "abstractions", but "compression" gets at the core reason we don't always want decoupling in our abstractions).

This makes it less likely we programmers working on the code would literally forget to think about the tests for a time. This might look something like changing the code first without a single thought to any tests, then running the tests later before releasing/pushing/merging, and seeing they still pass, not give any thought to whether more tests are warranted for the code they just wrote, given the nature of the changes.

It makes it harder for programmers to be lazy. If the test is "all the way over there", then the programmer has to find the test code, read over it, find the relevant portion to the code they were just looking at/thinking about changing. But if you have something more like a method that tests a method, followed by the method it is testing, you would have to be really lazy to not "feel like" finding the test.

If the programmers already care about code quality in the actual code, this approach helps them to care equally about the code quality in tests because there is less of a distinction between the two. This is really important, because the code quality in the tests is arguably even more important than the code quality of the rest of the code, because taking ridiculously good care of your test code is necessary to prevent the tests from eventually holding the team back more than they are helping them, which is actually the most difficult part of using tests well.

If you are doing TDD, or even writing some code and then immediately writing a test, you will often find yourself going back and forth between the test and the code, trying to compare the two. But if they are in the same class, this makes the act of comparing the two more natural, and less cognitively demanding. This also contributes to the tests not holding you back (emotionally and energetically) more than they help you, which could lead to getting frustrated with the tests and deleting them all.

It leads to more natural code reuse between the tests and the code. This serves a dual purpose. It allows you to merge the idea of runtime assertions  and tests into a single thing, at least some of the time. The way you would do that is have methods that serve no purpose other than to perform assertions that would throw an exception if they fail. Then you are free to reuse those assertion methods from both the code, to validate contracts, and in the tests, to validate the code. Validating contracts and throwing exceptions when they are violated is considered good practice anyways, and this makes it more natural. Then some of the tests can even become this simple thing where they merely execute the right methods in the right way, and the methods then literally somewhat test themselves, because they already call those assertion methods. You can then decide to leave all these assertions on when releasing the code, in order to enable better monitoring and reporting on production, or turn at least some of them off for faster code. They could even be enabled on production on an as needed basis when needing a higher level of reporting. The reuse also serves the purpose of lowering the overall amount of test code needed, thus helping us even more to keep the tests worth their weight.

Tests can be a nice form of documentation. By keeping the tests with the code, you are keeping the documentation with the code it is documenting, which is often the best way for programmers to truly understand the code.

It makes it easier to refactor in the case that you already had a one to one mapping between test files and code being tested. If you rename a class, you don't need to then also rename its test.

Placing the tests in the code makes it more natural to have a one to one mapping of tests and code it is testing. Some people say this is bad because tests should test behavior not classes/methods, but when that objection is valid it is actually a code smell. Code should be written in way that is both natural for the language it is written in, and almost makes it appear as if that language was designed just for your code. The code should then combine that concept with taking advantage of the language constructs such that the code is the most natural expression/specification of the actual end behavior as is possible in that language. If testing "the code" means you are not testing "the behavior", you already had a code quality problem. In type oriented programming (think object oriented programming, which in most modern OO languages is actually class oriented programming, which is actually type oriented programming because classes are a way for you to define your own types), this would make perfect sense because of course you want each type to be individually tested on a technical level (the accuracy of performing operations on the values of that type). This is because each new type you make essentially becomes a core part of the language you are writing code in, and you don't want your programming language itself to be buggy right? This also does not exclude programming end user features directly, because those can be implemented as their own type (think a type for each web page, or a type for each API command. So some types will be much closer to the end user, and others will be much more low level, but both need to bested at the type level, since that is what they are.